issue while updating python array
new = [{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]

I am trying to update the above array 0 element only using new[0]['indicator']='HMA' but after updating when trying to print then below response appears.
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}]

here i am trying to update only array 0 element but it's updated all the 4 elements.
Pls help me to solve the issue
after update process completed i need below response
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]


Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to ask a good question. Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add all the relevant code.

there is something else going on.
On Python 3.12.1, this is what I see.
>>> new = [{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> new[0]['indicator']='HMA'
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> 
>>> 


This is because you did not have that in your original code.
If you create an item x and then add it three times into a list, you will get the effect you describe.
>>> x = {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}
>>> new = [x,x,x]
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> new[0]['indicator']='HMA'
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}]
>>> 

What is happening is that the list is composed of three references to x, not three instances to x, and that persists when modifying x via any of it's references..
We can use the copy() method to instantiate. The following has two instances, the first is a new copy of x, the remainder are two references to the variable x.
>>> x = {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}
>>> new = [x.copy(),x,x]
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> new[0]['indicator']='HMA'
>>> new
[{'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'HMA'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}, {'n': '1234', 'indicator': 'RSI'}]
>>> 

OMFG-Why?  There are times when we want to use references, and other times when we want instances.  In python, anything beyond a primitive type is going to be treated as a reference (equivalent to a 'C'-style pointer)
This is useful, as it saves memory and time when constructing and deconstructing complex objects.  Moreover, in most cases, one will quickly be looking to convert complex data structures into classes, which are then handled according to their constructors.
new = [foo('n',1234,'HMA'),foo('n',1234,'RSI'),foo('n',1234,'RSI')]

I should point out that, unless '1234' is truly nominal, it should be stored numerically. This will save a lot of time when using, for instance, JSON for imports/exports.

solved, thanks for your detailed response. thank you again...

I think you can check the ID address of the element in the list。similar
for ele in new:
  print(id(ele))

If you point to the same ID address, modify the first element, and the subsequent elements will be changed.
You can use DeepCopy to ensure that the address of each element in the list is different.
